# Specify custom resolution in XCom

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, macos, xcom-enemy-within

I have the Steam version of XCom Enemy Within, and wish to configure it to use a higher resolution than the highest it gives me (1440 x 900).

I have modified my `/Users/<user>/Library/Application Support/Steam/SteamApps/common/XCom-Enemy-Unknown/XCOMData/XComGame/Config/DefaultEngine.ini` file to ensure it contains the following:

`[SystemSettings]
ResX=1920
ResY=1080`

But this has had no effect. A similar modification worked for me when I was playing this game on Windows 8.1.

Is it possible to play this game with custom resolutions on OS X, or has this facility been disabled for some reason?

*Update*:

I've also updated `~/Library/Application Support/Feral Interactive/XCOM Enemy Unknown/XEW/MacInit/XComEngine.ini` with the same content, to no avail.

Comment: can files be found here: ~/Library/Application Support/Feral Interactive/XCOM Enemy Unknown/ ? thats where the game config files should be found.

Comment: So I found `XcomEngine.ini` in this folder tree, and edited `ResX/Y` appropriately. It seems that the XCom "configurator" overwrites these values though.

Comment: On what kind of machine are you trying to play? It sounds like your os or graphics card dont support higher resolution

Comment: 2014 15" MBP w/ nvidia 750m

Comment: with retina display?

Comment: Yes with retina

Comment: then it supports 2560 x 1600 and this is the point i've no more ideas i'm sorry. Googled for a while now and can't find someone with a similar problem. But one more question, what do you mean with the "configurator"?

Comment: When you open XCom from steam, a pre-game configuration window opens up, you choose XCom or XCom:EW, then it opens the game. The same window allows you to choose the resolution.

Comment: sorry i have absolutely no more ideas then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the launch options to

```
-ResX=1920 -ResY=1080
```

Any options from http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/CommandLineArguments.html#Rendering  should work.